# Code not writing database to sdcard

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sdcard

I'm using the following code to export a copy of my database to my sdcard.

```
public class AgUtility extends AgActivity{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.utility);
    try {
        backupDatabase(getBaseContext());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}        
public static void backupDatabase(Context context) throws IOException {


    // Open your local db as the input stream
    String inFileName = "data/data/com.agmanagement.todaysstudent/databases/todaysstudent.db";
    Toast.makeText(context, "FileName Is "+ inFileName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.i("The File In Is ", inFileName);

    File dbFile = new File(inFileName);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dbFile);

    File outputDirectory = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/student/");
    outputDirectory.mkdir();
    Log.d("MAKE DIR", dbFile.mkdir() + "");
    String backupFileName = "/TodaysStudentTest.db3"; 
    String outFileName = outputDirectory + backupFileName;
    Toast.makeText(context, "Database backup names is " + outFileName , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
    .show();  

    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    // Close the streams
    output.flush();
    output.close();
    fis.close();

    Toast.makeText(context, "Database backup complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
}
}
```

The code seems to work properly, in that I don't get any errors the first Toast shows the correct database name, the second toast shows the output directory should be mnt/sdcard/student and the third shows the final target should be mnt/sdcard/student/TodaysStudentTest.db3

After that Toast fades, nothing, the final Toast never appears.

In my manifest I have

I am testing this on a Samsung Tablet and not on the emulator, i've also run it on a DroidX with the same result, no errors, but no folder is created.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?
TIA

The permissions I'm using are

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.premission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>
```

I get the same results when running in the emulator - watching with the DDMS - Logcat show MAKE DIR fails.

I've tested for state with this

```
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
         // We can read and write the media
         mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "We Can Read And Write To The SDCARD", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
         // We can only read the media
                mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
                mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "We Can Read The SDCARD", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                // Something else is wrong. It may be one of many other states, but all we need
                //  to know is we can neither read nor write
                mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "We Can't read or write", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

And it shows I'm supposed to be able to read and write, so there's something wrong with how I'm writing. I added this to also text

```
       boolean success = false;
        if(!outputDirectory.exists()){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Folder Doesn't Exist ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();  
            success = outputDirectory.mkdirs();
        }
        if (!success){ 
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Folder Not Created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();  
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Folder Created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();  
        }
```

Results are folder does not exist, and then mkdirs() fails.

Comment: Just out of curiosity why are you making a directory inside your logcat statement, that you don't use? `Log.d("MAKE DIR", dbFile.mkdir() + "");`

Comment: I changed that back to match the line above, I was trying to see if mkdir was working

Comment: I found a simplified method, see my update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**REWRITE**

Here is a different approach to coping a database file, without using SQL itself or a looping buffer.

NOTE: This isn't actually copied to the sdcard, the backup is stored in the original databases folder (which I like because you **do not need** WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission).

```
public class FileIO extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        DBHelper db = new DBHelper(this);

        try { 
            copyFile();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            Log.i("Main", "Complete");
            db.close();
            finish();
        }
    }

    public void copyFile() throws IOException {
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

        /* Create file first
            FileOutputStream created = openFileOutput("copyFile.db", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            created.close();
        */

        String currentDBPath = "/data/<your_path>/databases/data.db";
        String backupDBPath = "/data/<your_path>/databases/copyByFile.db";
        File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
        File backupDB = new File(data, backupDBPath);

        if (currentDB.exists()) {
            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            src.close();
            dst.close();
        }
        else
            Log.i("Main", "Current db does not exist");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've inserted a try - catch and was able to find out that it's not creating the file-folder - could there be an issue because both target machines are tethered to my development machine?

Comment: I'm baffled.  I even tried downloading it from the app marketplace and it's just not creating the target folder and file

Comment: Which permissions are you using? (+1 for executable code, by the way)

Comment: Sam, I appended those to my original post

Comment: I am reading through [this link](http://www.anddev.org/working_with_files-t115.html) which details why standard Java IO doesn't work on Android and how to do it the _Android_ way.

Comment: That link gave me working IO commands, let me know if you have trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Try to manually create file before trying to write to it.

Comment: For some reason I'm not being allowed to write to the sd cards, it's happening with both machines

                    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

               if (sd.canWrite()) {
     
Returns a false

Comment: Yes, I've checked it several times, when I look at the app in the 'manage apps' on both the phone and the tablet though, it doesn't show up as one of the permissions.  Under Hardware controls, it just lists take pictures and videos.

Comment: by design mkdirs() doesn't throw an exception it only returns a true or false

Comment: By design, it does. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir()

Comment: It only throws a securityexception with no detail or a null pointer exception, neither of which is showing up in my logcat so I'm not sure how to use this to help find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

please make sure you have already created folder named "student" as you are using mkdir(). it will create directory by abstract path name..so if folder "student" does not exist it wont create new folder.. or try instead mkdirs(). it will created parent folder if necessary.

Comment: I've changed the code to mkdirs() and have tested for the existence of the folder and it comes up that the folder doesn't exist, but even mkdirs() fails.

Comment: is it throwing any exception?

Answer (score 0):

Important to remember to check spelling.  uses-permission was mis-spelled as uses-premission, I had read the code so many times I read it as I wanted it to be.  valuable lesson, walk away and take a break.